# How can use multiple inheritance in android activity?

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I want to use RxLifeCycle because compose(bindToLifeCycle), but I already use DaggerAppCompatActivity.

bindToLifeCycle need to RxAppCompactActivity. However, Java doesn't support multiple inheritance. How can I solve?

BaseActivity

```
public class BaseActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity{ }
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity { }
```

I want

```
public class BaseActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity, RxAppCompactActivity { }
```

but this code can't use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the implementation of `DaggerAppCompatActivity` by pressing `Ctrl+B` on it in your IDE, you'll see that the only difference is the call to `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` before `super.onCreate()`.

So you can extend `RxLifecycleActivity` and write `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` before `super.onCreate()` and you'll get equivalent results.

You can also copy the stuff in `RxLifecycleActivity` into your BaseActivity too. You can do both. It's up to you really. Just copy an implementation of those base classes into your own class and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support Multiple Inheritance.
Though can use Interface and implement multiple interfaces in your class.

[tutorial for interface](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm)

Comment: I know Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, but i want to use RxAppCompatActivity and DaggerAppCompatActivtiy in one Actiivty.